# WPF: Is there a way to use a ValueConverter without defining a resource?

Tags: wpf

Is there a way to use a ValueConverter without defining it in a resource? As is the syntax is pretty verbose.

Comment: how about reflection to scan you assembly and register valueconverters?

Comment: The syntax to use a converter without defining a resource is even more verbose.

Comment: Maybe I could make a subclass of Binder that takes a string and does the reflection lookup.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a MarkupExtension to minimise the amount of xaml code required. E.g:

```
public class  MyConverter: MarkupExtension, IValueConverter
```

{
    private static MyConverter _converter;

```
public object Convert(object  value, Type targetType, 
object  parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
{
    // convert and return something
}

public object  ConvertBack(object value, Type  targetType, 
object parameter,  System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
{
    // convert and return something (if needed)
}

public override object  ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
{
    if (_converter == null)
        _converter = new MyConverter();
    return _converter;
}
```

}

You end up with a syntax like this:

```
{Binding Converter={conv:MyConverter}}
```

This approach has an added advantage of ensuring that all your converters are singletons.

This [article](http://shortfastcode.blogspot.com/2010/07/better-way-to-declare-your.html) does a great job of explaining the concept and provides sample code.

Comment: +1 you beat me by 10 seconds :) Here is another link... http://drwpf.com/blog/2009/03/17/tips-and-tricks-making-value-converters-more-accessible-in-markup/

Answer (score 7):

Within your converter you can have a static property or field that you can refer to in xaml. No need for adding a resource.

```
 public class MyConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public static readonly MyConverter Instance = new MyConverter();
... }
```

And in XAML

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=., Converter={x:Static l:MyConverter.Instance}}" />
```

Beaware that these converters should not store any state as the same instance will be used.
If you are iffy about public fields just create a static property instead.

Though it is debatable that this is better

Comment: +1 for teaching me a new technique, but I think the thing I care most about is making the binding declaration shorter. I'm seriously thinking about dumping converters entirely and switching back to PyBinding.

Answer (score 0):

You could create an attach property to hook up to the binding and perform the conversion, though if the only reason is for breverity, I wouldn't recommend adding an extra piece of complexity to your code.

Answer (score 0):

How exactly are you declaring these converters such that verbosity is an issue?

```
<conv:NegatingConverter x:Key="NegatingConverter" />
```

One line per converter per application.

Usage isn't verbose either.

```
Converter="{StaticResource NegatingConverter}"
```

Comment: Ideally we would only have to write Converter="NegatingConverter", everything else is line noise needed to make the compiler happy.